# Building intuition in group theory

Tags: group-theory, intuition

I'm finding it hard to translate abstract results of group theory into something that intuitively makes sense.

Putting this into a concrete example: if $f:G\to H$, $Im(G)$, is a subgroup of $H$? Is there an intuitive reason why this should be so?

More generally, does anyone have any tips for helping to 'understand' a result in a deeper sense than simply knowing that it's true?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by the image of a group?

Comment: OK, this reveals my lack of understanding. I'll edit the question

Comment: When it comes to learning group theory, it is often helpful to think of some symmetry groups of objects you know, either in the form of transformation groups of the plane, or in the form of small cyclical/dihedral groups. If you understand the basic concepts for these, you're well on you're way to understand the concepts more generally.

Comment: Understanding a deep result requires knowing not only the result itself, but also its proof. If you read through a proof several times (or even better, work out the proof yourself several times), you'll definitely feel like you understand a theorem more than if you read the proof once and forget it.

Comment: I think you meant $f(G)$ by $Im(G)$. Observe that your statement is not necessarily true. However, if you let $f$ be a homomorphism, then it becomes true. There's a question about intuition for homomorphism, worth reading answers. Also, the best way to understand a theorem is trying to find a counter-example (of course you will not be able to find a counter-example even if you try very extreme examples)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we come across any kind of mathematical/algebraic object, one of things we should define is the notion **structure preserving map** between two such objects. Such a map should preserve the key properties of the structure.

A homomorphism of groups is a function that preserves the key structure of the group. Think about the conditions for $\theta:G\to H$ to be a homomorphism: we have

1. $\theta(e_G) = e_H$ - i.e. $\theta$ takes the identity in $G$ to the identity in $H$
2. $\theta(g*g')=\theta(g)*\theta(g')$ - i.e. $\theta$ preseves multiplicaton

As a corollary of (1) and (2) we can also show that

3. $\theta(g^{-1}) = \theta(g)^{-1}$ - i.e $\theta$ preserves inverses

In other words, the map $\theta$ preserves the defining structure of our group. As such, it makes sense that $\operatorname{Im}(\theta)$ should also be a group, since it inherits its group structure from $G$.